# Any way to know how a secret got deleted from kubernetes namespace

Tags: kubernetes

A secret went missing in one of my Kubernetes namespaces. Either some process or somebody deleted this accidentally.
Is there a way to find out how this got deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If [audit logging](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/audit/) was enabled on the cluster at the time, then yes. Some hosted Kubernetes clusters (GKR, AKS, ...) can be enabled for this too, but you haven't specified the kind of cluster/provider. Otherwise there is no way.